# Como transformar um número de decimal para binário utilizando String

Tags: c

Bom eu consegui utilizando números inteiros, só que o professor quer que código aceite número muito grande que não cabem no inteiro, ele falou que tinha que ler como uma string, só que eu não sei como isso pode ser feito

Meu código utilizando números inteiros

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int num, aux, vetor[90], i = 0;

   scanf("%d", &num);
   while(num >= 1)
   {
     aux = num;
     num = num / 2;
     aux = aux % 2;
     vetor[i++] = aux;
   }
   for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
   {
      printf("%d", vetor[j]);
   }
   putchar('\n');
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.programasprontos.com/algoritmos-conversores/conversao-decimal-para-binario-c/ Aqui um Artigo para você

Comment: Um `long` é aceitável? Tem que ser *string* mesmo? Dá bem mais trabalho.

Comment: olá maneiro por isso ele passou com String, ele falou que é um super desafio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a função [sprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), usando os valores da tabela [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int num, aux, i = 0;
   char vetor[200];

   scanf("%d", &num);
   while(num >= 1)
   {
     aux = num;
     num = num / 2;
     aux = aux % 2;
     sprintf(&vetor[i++],"%c",aux+'0');
   }
   for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
   {
      printf("%c", vetor[j]);
   }
   putchar('\n');
   return 0;
}
```

ou então, de forma mais simples, apenas converta o valor numérico para codificação [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII):

```
while(num >= 1)
{
    aux = num;
    num = num / 2;
    aux = aux % 2;
    vetor[i++] = aux+'0';
}
```